# How should Genesis 3:20 be rendered?

Tags: genesis, adam, eve

Should it be “And Adam called his wife’s name Eve, because she WAS the mother of all living”? Or should it be “And Adam called his wife’s name Eve, because she WOULD BECOME the mother of all living”?

Do both work equally well? I am asking for what the best / most accurate translation is.

I find it curious that Eve is called this when she is not the mother of Adam, and has not birthed Cain yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Excellent question. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 4):

הָֽיְתָ֖ה is the [third person singular and is the Qal perfect of the verb 'to come'](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/3-20.htm).

Therefore 'was become' is the translation, in context.

---

The word הָֽיְתָ֖ה occurs [111 times in the bible and is variously translated](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/hayetah_1961.htm) according to context bearing in mind the way scriptural Hebrew treats of the future in cases where God is involved and the future becomes a certainty.

God promised that through woman a seed would arise which would rise above the angelic power of the spirit which had behaved in a serpentine manner. That seed would come of woman, not man, and would bruise the head of the serpent (from above).

Thus birth of woman, ascension, and triumph are all envisaged.

*Therefore*, Adam calls his wife by a name.

---

Because *she was become* (by the certainty of the promise of God) the mother of all that truly live, that is to say that are empowered by the tree of life through the incarnation of the promised seed and the triumph of that seed over the angelic power that had brought sin into the world.

Adam has admitted his fault, and has been provided, by God almighty, with the token of a coming humanity, skin (not ascribed to any species) and thus a covering, a containment, a new humanity.

Adam responds, for the first time with faith, and believes the promise of God and acts upon the promise. Thus his household becomes an household of faith for when Cain goes out, he goes out 'from the presence of God' despite that the first humanity has been banished from Eden.

---

For the presence of God is within the Adam household, by faith. For Adam believed God and called his wife 'Eve', for she was become, by God's promise, the mother of that which would come and give life to all that should live.

That is to say, life out of the death of a fallen humanity, by means of the promised seed.

Comment: Didn't Adam name his wife 'Eve' because he knew she would be the mother of the living?

Comment: @JoshuaB   Yes, but the _text_ says that 'she _was become_' that.

Comment: WOULD become mother of the living?

Comment: @JoshuaB It is the Qal perfect :  a past tense. You are attempting to make it a future tense (or even a subjunctive ?) and it is not.

Comment: You're right. She was mother of the living. So you're saying this means that Adam was sure that Eve was mother of the living despite Cain and Abel being born yet, because of the sureness of promises made by God?

Answer (score 0):

Adam named his wife Eve because she was the mother of the living, in that Adam was confident in God's promises to him.

Adam was sure that Eve would be mother of the living, so in being confident about that promise, she *was* already mother of the living in his mind.

The Hebrew word is הָֽיְתָ֖ה hayahtah, which generally means "was". Adam was certain that Eve **was** mother of the living because he knew that the promises of God always come to fruition.

Answer (score -1):

How does this affect the way you live your life? So much  of what we read in the Bible (and other scriptures) depends on the translation, edition, etc., and how we understand its meaning. So very much of the Bible is allegorical and can be read on differeent levels.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to the group, Anthony. The reason your answer received a downvote is that it's more of a comment than an answer. The catch-22 is that you can't leave comments until you have a reputation score of 50. The way to improve your score is by getting up-votes on either questions or answers. Many new users get discouraged by this, but please don't give up.

Comment: by the way, sometimes studying the Bible is like doing a puzzle: figuring out even small points is enjoyable - all the more so because the process helps us put together  the Big Picture

Comment: That's absolutely right Dan. Everything fits into the grand big picture of things.